# Install failure from Apple store

Tags: ipad, installation, itunes-store

I recently uploaded a new version for one of my applications as an update for which I already had an initial version on Store.
After it's release few clients (to be precise 2) have reported that the application does n't install on their device.

**Issues:** a) Application doesn't installs on their iPads. b) The application doesn;t go past splash screen on one of client's devices.
**What I have done** To find out the install issues I test ran the same build on all availble devices I had but it ran smoothly. I sent them an Adhoc build with Crashlytics integrated however it did not serve an good as they could not install that as well.

*Now the Build details are as follows for the version on apple store* 
    Deployment Target: 5.1
    Required Capabilities :     armv7
    Supported Architectures :   armv7
    Device Family :     iPad
    Newsstand App :     false

Note 1: Both clients did a clean install.
Note 2: The application does some initial set up . Unzipping Images archives and setting up initial database. The app uses core data for db purpose.

If some one could guide me as to what should I do to grab the potential issues it will be of great help. Please let me know if I need to mention more info with my question to help understand the issues.

Comment: What's the version of the iPad? Did you get any crash logs from Apple?

Comment: No,there aren't any crash logs since the app doesn't even install. I sent a build with crashalytics installed but even that did not help. The iOS version is 6.1.3 on which this doesn't install.